# XCTest: Passing a function parameter

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest, xctestexpectation

From XCTest file, I am calling a web service call and had put a wait block using "self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout" API and to get the service response.

I have few test methods to be executed with this service response. When I store this response in a global variable and access it from other test function, this variable is coming as nil. What needs to be done here? Can I pass it as a function parameter?

```
let serviceResp :NSDictionary!

func test_One() {
        //let expectation: XCTestExpectation = self.expectationWithDescription("HTTP")

        datamanager.fetchData() //Web service

        self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in

//In 5 seconds, I will get response from service and will be stored in datamanager.response. 

    self.serviceResp = datamanager.response
        })
    }


    func test_Two() {
       //self.serviceResp is coming as nil even after assigning a value to it. 
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Let's see some code! :)

Comment: Added high level code.

Comment: You get the response in five seconds, but the other test function runs long before that!

Comment: That is not the case Matt. test_two will be executed only after 5 seconds

Comment: Well so maybe `dataManager.response` _is_ nil. The fact that you are hitting the 5 second timeout suggests that your connection might be failing.

Comment: I am getting the service response. I am able to perform few operations inside wait block. But not from the test_two function.

Comment: By the way, this is not directly relevant to your question, but your test is missing some pieces: you must create an XCTestExpectation object (you've commented that out) and you must call `fulfill` on it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass information between XCTest methods in this way. See the following from the [Testing with Xcode Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/testing_3_writing_test_classes/testing_3_writing_test_classes.html) (Emphasis mine)

> For each class, testing starts by running the class setup method. **For
>   each test method, a new instance of the class is allocated** and its
>   instance setup method executed. After that it runs the test method,
>   and after that the instance teardown method. This sequence repeats for
>   all the test methods in the class. After the last test method teardown
>   in the class has been run, Xcode executes the class teardown method
>   and moves on to the next class. This sequence repeats until all the
>   test methods in all test classes have been run.

If there is information that all your test need to run, consider putting it in the setup method.